# why my output is not display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

why my output (refresh value) is not displayed

```js
function myFunction() {
  $a = document.getElementById("examplehtml").value;
  document.write("<big><bold>");
  document.write($a);
  document.write("</bold></big>");
  $b = document.getElementById("refresh").value;
  document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="');
  document.write($b);
  document.write('"/>');

}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:myFunction()" method="get">
  <input name="refresh" value="60" type="text" id="refresh">
  <input name="examplehtml" value="i am is output from input examplehtml, but my input refresh is blank" type="text" id="examplehtml">
  <input type="submit" value="ENTER ">
</form>
```

result of the value from examplehtml is displayed, but value from refresh in blank

Comment: do you want to pass a PHP variable to Javascript?

Comment: Please read [ask] then explain what you are trying to do in proper detail. Broken code is not a good substitute for a concise explanation of exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Personally I still can't get it, what does that mean: "refresh my page use input refresh "?

Comment: yes sir i want to refresh my page use input refresh

Answer (score -2, accepted):

String concatenation in JavaScript is done using the `+` operator.
You can achieve what you want using something like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    var $c= document.getElementById("refresh").value;
    document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'+$c+'"/>');
}
```

You also have to declare variables using the `var` keyword.

Comment: I think he wants the `$d` variable from PHP in the content attr

Comment: come on ... `document.write`... really??

Comment: @charlietfl That is what the PHP script does.

Comment: No it doesn't. `document.write` wipes out the whole page when used after page load. Also the form will submit.

Comment: @Ivan there is no `$d` variable in either PHP or JavaScript I just assumed based on the PHP script that this is what the OP is looking for (using the input's value as the meta element's content attribute value).

Comment: @charlietfl and the PHP just echoes a single element the result of which is a document with a single element.

Comment: @Titus, that's why I think he wants to echo a PHP variable.

Comment: Makes no sense. User clicks a button and the whole page goes blank. I highly doubt that is the expected behavior

Comment: ok, now this answer is accepted...

Comment: i want to refresh my page use input refresh

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: write the site name in the input box, click on <kbd>E N T E R</kbd>. It will redirect you to the site.

```js
function myFunction(){
  url = document.getElementById('refresh').value;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="write url here" type="text" id="refresh">
<button onclick="myFunction()">E N T E R</button>
```

Write `https://stackoverflow.com` to test it.

Comment: please use snippet

Comment: First, tell me what you want to do with `myFunction()`! Do you want a refresh button? a navigate button? a for validation button?

Comment: i want to refresh button use input

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't mean anything, can you explain?

Comment: I want visitors to determine the refresh value of my page

Comment: if ($_GET['refresh']){
  echo"<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"".$_GET['refresh']."\">";}

Comment: look at my edit please

Comment: not input url @ivan, but input number to sending request value of the meta tag refresh page

Comment: Honestly I can't figure out what you want (what language do you speak) can you try to rephrase your question? Why have you accepted Titus's question?

Comment: please run my snippet again

Comment: so 1) the user enters a number, 2) he clicks on `E N T E R` 3) a new page is loaded? where do you want the number to go?